# Combo doesn't show his options

Tags: html, combobox, internet-explorer-6

I'm developing in IE6. I have a simple combobox with three options (the empty default one, and two others).

Sometimes, this combo shows the options in the right way, like this: [image: Combo with options]

But other times, the combo has the same options, but it doesn't show them, like this: [image: Combo with hidden options]

The options are provably there because I can put the mouse in the combo and, with the mouse wheel, I can go up and down and make a selection. But the combo doesn't open (or drilldown, I don't know the right verb).

Other combos in the same view show their options well, they have a CSS class like this:

```
 .myStyle { width: 170px; padding:1px 0px 1px 0px; }
```

This 'rebel' combo also has this style. What am I doing wrong? Is this a CSS issue?

Note that the combo is inside a cell in a table. The code is:

```
<select id="mySelect" class="myStyle">
     <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

In the JavaScript section, if I don't use this jQuery code, the combo options are never shown:

```
$("#mySelect").css("width","auto");
```

Because of this, at least sometimes, the combo options can be shown.

Comment: Please show us the HTML code for your field as well as the CSS.

Comment: Any time anyone says "IE6 is a requirement", tell them it will cost twice as much to develop and not be as good. See if it's still a requirement after that.

Comment: @Spudley the code is in the post body. About IE6, I agree to you, but it's the official corporate browser, and the web must be prepared for that. Why don't they migrate to IE7, IE8, FF...? It's annoying, but I don't know.Thanks for your attention. Best regards

Comment: A combobox is a drop down menu combined with a text input, you can't have one in HTML without using a pile of JavaScript. You appear to have a simple drop down menu. Don't confuse the terms.

Comment: @DavidDorward, while I was writting the question, I didn't know the rigth words in English. My component is a simple select in HTML, without text input, like this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp    Thanks. Greetings

Comment: can you assemble a live reproduction? running [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lv63/) on IE6 doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is: replace IE6.

The rare tip to fix this annoying problem is this:

```
$("select").each(function(){
 $(this).css("width","auto");
 $(this).attr('size', 2).attr('size', 1);});
```

Yeah, I know, it's a strange patch, but it was the only idea it really works.
And I repeat: change to newer IE than 6 version.